# Issue in showing events accurately in fullcalendar Month view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i am using FullCalendar v2.7.1 jquery plugin.

It is not showing the events correctly in **month view**. In **day view** and **week view** it shows events accurately. 
I have passed events with datetime in **ISO8601** format (2016-08-06T00:00:00).

I have an event start at **2016-08-02T07:00:00** and end at **2016-08-04T07:00:00**
But in month view the event occupied in only **2 days** (August 02 - August 03)
instead of **3 days** (August 02 - August 04)

But when i changed my end date to **2016-08-04T09:00:00** it occupied to **3 days**.

My js code for full calendar is

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false,
    droppable: false,
    events:{
        url: "common/calendar/show_events",
        type: 'POST'
    }
});
```

i have tried **allDayDefault** to false also.

Is there any solution to solve this?

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that shows the problem?

Comment: Yes. please see https://jsfiddle.net/sqhwLrwv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just issue of your timezone, try to match timezone with your pc timezone
I always prefer to pass dates and time using unix timestamps

Ex: 
start: 1470747280000

If it is not fixed by timestamp then look for following settings:

```
nextDayThreshold: '00:00:00'
```

Following link may help you to understand timezone:
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/

Logically it is three days between 2016-08-02T07:00:00 and 2016-08-04T09:00:00
2nd Aug, 3rd Aug and on 4th Aug 9 hours
So, it would show on 4th august

Comment: Then y it is not showing on  4th august (3 days) when passing 2016-08-02T07:00:00 and 2016-08-04T07:00:00
Me showing only 2 days

Comment: Look for one more setting called timezoneParam: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/timezoneParam/ and try to pass datetime in same format

Comment: tried not working. can u look at this jsfiddle demo https://jsfiddle.net/sqhwLrwv/

Comment: Add following:  nextDayThreshold: '00:00:00',
This will help to resolve it
https://jsfiddle.net/v8qszkxx/

Comment: It is the issue of nextDayThreshold